# Room error: no viable alternative at input?

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying to update the table using @Query annotation of room library, below is my code ( In Dao interface ) :

```
@Query("UPDATE table_name SET table_name.col1 = :val1 WHERE table_name.col2 = :val2")
void updateValue(long val1, long val2);
```

Complete error string as below :

```
Error:(11, 10) error: no viable alternative at input 'UPDATE table_name SET table_name.'
```

Here is entity class :

```
@Entity(tableName = "table_name")
public class SampleTable {

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
    private Long Id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "col1")
    private Long column1;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "col2")
    private Long column2;

    public Long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public Long getColumn1() {
        return column1;
    }

    public void setColumn1(Long column1) {
        this.column1 = column1;
    }

    public Long getColumn2() {
        return column2;
    }

    public void setColumn2(Long column2) {
        this.column2 = column2;
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your Java class with the `@Entity` annotation that defines `table_name`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have edited the question please have a look, thanks

Comment: Try changing your statement to `UPDATE table_name SET col1 = :val1 WHERE col2 = :val2`. You do not need the table prefix in this case, and the error message makes it feel like Room is tripping over the prefix.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are absolutely right I removed the table_name and the error is gone, thanks. I didn't expected such behavior. Thanks.

Comment: It feels like a Room bug, to be honest. If you are in position to create a project that serves as a reproducible test case, [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:197448) and upload the sample project there. If you do not think that you will have time for that, let me know, and I'll see if I can toss something together.

Comment: Sure I can file this issue thanks for the suggestion, I have this sample experimental table_name which I can use to create sample then I will file bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your statement to:

```
UPDATE table_name SET col1 = :val1 WHERE col2 = :val2.
```

The error message makes it feel like Room is tripping over the prefix.

<strike>This is a bug in Room, at least through `1.0.0-alpha8`. Track [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64539805) to see when it gets fixed.</strike>

That's actually not valid SQLite syntax, [as it turns out](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64539805#comment5). Table prefixes go on columns in `SELECT` statements, [not `UPDATE` statements](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html).

Answer (score 13):

This error could also happen in this case:

If you are passing a list, don't forget to add the parentheses enclosing your list variable, otherwise you will get the same error:

```
@Query("select name from mytable where name in (:myList)")
LiveData<List<String>> findNames(List<String> myList);
```

Comment: That really helped! :D

Answer (score 0):

In my case a message was `error: no viable alternative at input 'is'` (and a query name was mentioned). I found that the query didn't have necessary spaces between words like here:

```
    "from car" +       // Add a space here.
    "where brand_id is null" +
```